# CKEditor resizable and draggable at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, ckeditor

i'm trying to make a resizable/draggable CKEditor but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I made a wrapper div containing the CKEditor "editable" inline div.

Applied jQUery UI draggable() to the wrapper div, it works, but in order to edit with CKEditor, i need to make like 3 clicks on the entire div, why is that?

Also, is there a possibility to get the "is Editor Active" event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found to this problem was to force focus in the inner div when the wrapper receive a click event:

```
wrapper.on "click", ->
  new_div.focus()
```

Comment: This has the problem that you can't select text in ckeditor. The best way that I find to get around this was to use a [handle](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle) and put it outside the div, using `position: absolute` and negative values for `left`.